# SimpleDateFormat parse off by 5 hours - Timezone issue?

Tags: java, android, simpledateformat

Because of the consistency of the problem, and the fact that I am in GMT-5, I believe this to be a timezone issue. My code is below

```
MediaMetadataRetriever mdr = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
mdr.setDataSource(path);
date = mdr.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_DATE);

try {
     date = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy   h:mm a", Locale.getDefault()).format(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmss", Locale.getDefault()).parse(date));
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Several things I did to fix it include the following code:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmss", Locale.getDefault());
sdf.setTimezone(TimeZone.getDefaultTimezone);

try {
    date = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy   h:mm a", Locale.getDefault()).format(sdf.parse(date));
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

However, nothing changed. I would like to be able to use the default timezone for each device.

Any help is appreciated

EDIT: So the timezone works if I put
    sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Eastern Standard Time"));

but not with
    sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());

Also, here is some sample input/output with the TimeZone.getDefault() method:
input: 20170121T212723 output: Jan 22, 2017 2:27 am (note how the raw date/time is January 21st, but the formatted one is January 22nd) Expected output would be Jan 21, 2017  9:27 pm

So maybe this question is more about why doesn't TimeZone.getDefault() return the right timezone?

Comment: "Because of the consistency of the problem..." what's the problem?

Comment: To help to avoid this whole time zone malarkey, I would suggest using the `java.time` package that comes with Java 8.  In this case, you can parse it to a [`LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html), which doesn't deal with time zones.

Comment: @JoeC LocalDateTime and other Java 8 features are not yet supported in Android Studio

Comment: The problem can certainly be solved with `SimpleDateFormat` (although there are better APIs around), but you have not yet shown your input and expected and real output. So how can we help then?

Comment: @MenoHochschild updated to add input/output

Comment: Maybe `TimeZone.getDefault()` is simply not what you think (expected: GMT-05). Have you tried to print this expression? If the user has chosen another default zone than you intended then you should better set the timezone on sdf-formatter not to default zone but to the expected one (if you know for sure how to interprete the input since the input has NO timezone information). The correct interpretation of input strongly depends on where does it come from and in what zone it is intended.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it will be useful for someone.
The reason is that TimeZone.getDefault () returns a response in the form of a ZoneInfo object while getTimeZone ("Eastern Standard Time") returns a response in the form of a SimpleTimeZone object.

So this solution worked for me in kotlin (I think the result will be the same in java):

sdf.timeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault().toString()))